# passing pointer as argument to function in py

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 function that use the same variable, like this:

```
some_function():
    #do something with MyDict
    MyDict = dict()
    MyDict['name'] = 'hallo'

main():
    #do something else with MyDict
    MyDict['age'] = 33
    some_function()
```

I don't want to use `global` and let say that `MyDict` is very big and I don't want to pass it to `some_function`. what is the best way to do so? there is a way to pass a pointer to `MyDict`?
PS: I'm using py3.2

Answer (score 1):

In short: when you pass a `dict` as argument to a function, only the reference is passed, the data is not copied.

However, in general the parameters are references but some types are mutables but others aren't which changes the behavior.

Comment: For more clarification, @orenma you should take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/2689986